# SELECT with almost dynamic WHERE clause

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, pg

I am building an API with node/express and using PG and Postgres along with them.
At some point, I am trying to build a query that looks like this :

```
SELECT * FROM user_dog_view
WHERE dog_name = X AND dog_gender = Y AND dog_race = Z;
```

(The X, Y, Z represent info coming from the request.body or the query string)

Thing is: I would like my query to ignore one of the CONDITIONS in the WHERE clause lwhere the X, Y or Z is undefined or null (meaning the request.body or query string is incomplete).
E.g, if Y is undefined, I would like the query be like :

```
SELECT * FROM user_dog_view
WHERE dog_name = X AND dog_race = Z;
```

I tried looking into the coalesce ffunction but it does not seem to answer my needs.
Now I am wondering if I should try to put some complicated conditions to handle that thanks to JavaScript, but I am not sure that's the best idea?
Any Psql (or JS) insight on this is appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: You don't need complicated SQL conditions, you just need to build the "WHERE" clauses in your code.  If X is empty, then don't add the `dog_name = X` clause, and so on.

Comment: Are you using psql with express? It is anti-pattern because psql is a cli program. Use pg or sequelize to achieve your goal, they have fit solutions for this.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize
https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg

Comment: @TimRoberts: Thanks for your answer. What you are telling me is that I should handle the conditions (if X is empty then do not add `dog_name = X`) thanks to JavaScript?

Comment: @NaorLevi: Thank you too! I should have been more specific: I am indeed using PG with Express: are you referring to the use of parametirized query? (https://node-postgres.com/features/queries). (And I wanted to avoid using Sequelize since I am building my own hand-made Active Record ORM, but thanks for your advice though).